# How to have a free-standing bathtub resurfaced

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

I have a nice free-standing claw-foot tub.  It was re-finished poorly by a previous homeowner and now we're getting white flakes in the water.  There are also rust spots in a couple of places.

There seem to be several techniques for refinishing tubs but I'd like to do it right.  What should I be looking for as I shop for contractors to do the job?  What questions do I need to be asking?

Comment: I wound up buying a new tub. Not counting the fly-by-night people offering this service, the estimates I was getting were almost 50% of the price of a new tub.

Answer (score 4):

Best thing you can do is ask for references.  Call some people who had their tub refinished several years ago and see how it's holding up.

I've had this done a few times and it's a bit of a black art.  They have to be really meticulous with their prep work or the new finish won't last.

Also, you need to be careful what you clean it with after they refinish it!  Abrasive cleaners will destroy the finish.